# Integral calculus in Minkowski space-time

Tags: integration

Consider a real 4-dimensional Minkowski space-time with the usual inner product:
$$p\cdot q = p_0\cdot q_0 - p_1\cdot q_1 - p_2\cdot q_2 - p_3\cdot q_3$$

$$p^2 = p_0^2 - p_1^2 - p_2^2 - p_3^2$$

Let $S_{12}, S_{23}, S_{31}$ be  3 real constants.
The sum of these constants is called $S$:

$$S_{12} + S_{23} + S_{31} = S$$

I should want the result of the following integral (if it is not infinite):

$$
I = \int (d^4p_1) (d^4p_2) (d^4p_3) δ(p_1^2) δ(p_2^2) δ(p_3^2) δ(p_1.p_2 -S_{12}) δ(p_2\cdot p_3 -S_{23}) δ(p_3\cdot p_1 -S_{31})
$$

I am interested in the result, first when $S=0$, then in the general case $(S \neq 0)$